# C# MVC 3 Validation Failing on Particular Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, razor, validation

This is my first question posted here, so forgive me if there's anything missing. I'll update with any info requested.

**Explanation**

I'm working on my first C#.Net MVC-3 application. I'm using Entity Framework 4.0 and the Razor view engine.

For most of the views, I use a view model that contains instances of a partial class. That partial class is derived from the EF classes, and contains the data annotations on those class members. This worked pretty slick, and now all of my views that use that view model have validation for the affected text boxes. Examples:

*Partial Class:*

```
[MetadataType(typeof(DataPackageMetaData))]
public partial class DataPackage
{
    //empty
}

public class DataPackageMetaData
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DataPackageID { get; set; }

    ... (a lot more stuff like this) ...
}
```

*Viewmodel:*

```
public class PackageInfo
{
    // Registration Package information
    public DataPackage package { get; set; }
    public Reviewer reviewer { get; set; }
    public PackageTracking trackingSave { get; set; }

    <...>

    //Constructor
    public PackageInfo()
    {
        package = new DataPackage();
        reviewer = new Reviewer();
        trackingSave = new PackageTracking();
    }
}
```

So, all of the validation stuff for that stuff "just works." In the view (which is actually part of a partial view), I just put a "TextBoxFor." and then if the validation fails, a nice error message is posted in red:

*View:*

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.package.DataPackageID, new { @class = "short", @id = "DataPackageID" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.package.DataPackageID, "The Data Package ID is required and cannot be longer than 50 characters")
```

**Problem**

The problem I'm having is now that I've moved onto the reporting aspect of the program, I want a new ViewModel that can pass "DateIn" and "DateOut" form values (among other things) so that custom report queries can be generated. I want to be able to validate that the DateIn and DateOut values are, indeed, date values. For some reason, this isn't working.

*ViewModel:*

```
public class PackageVals
{
    < ... >

    // Date value for formatted "Date In" value
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Date In")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateIn { get; set; }

    // Date value for formatted "Date Out" value
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Date Out")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOut { get; set; }

    <... more stuff ...>
}
```

*View*

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.DateIn, new { @class = "small", @id = "DateIn"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.DateIn, "A valid date must be entered in the format mm/dd/yyyy.")
<...>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.DateOut, new { @class = "small", @id = "DateOut"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.DateOut, , "A valid date must be entered in the format mm/dd/yyyy.")
```

Note that in all cases I'm using partial views that are then embedded in other views. There are several different views in the report generation section of the app, and almost all of them will need the "DateIn" and "DateOut" form values.

I'm running out of things to look at, and time to look at them in. Right now, I just error-trap bad date values in the Controller and pass back a null ViewModel to keep the user from seeing a yellow screen of death.

I know the validation is based off jQuery, but I don't think I'm doing anything there that could cause the issue. Here's my entire jQuery script:

*jQuery Script*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Purple box autocomplete Stuff
    $("#Product").autocomplete({ source: '/SharedFunctions/AutoFillProduct' });
    $("#ActiveIngredient").autocomplete({ source: '/SharedFunctions/AutoFillActiveIngredient' });
    $("#Applicant").autocomplete({ source: '/SharedFunctions/AutoFillApplicant' });

    // Purple box autocomplete Stuff
    $("#DataType").autocomplete({ source: '/SharedFunctions/AutoFillDataType' });

    // Purple Box datepicker stuff
    $("#DateReceived").datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" });
    $("#OutDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" });

    // Silver box datepicker stuff; Also used by Reports
    $("#DateIn").datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" });
    $("#DateOut").datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" });

    // Alternate table row colors
    $("table.center > tbody tr:even").css("background-color", "#F2F8FF");
});
```

Any help you could give me with figuring this out would be great. Let me know if there's anything else you need.

Thanks again.

**Additional Info**

I wanted clarify, in case there is any confusion:
I have two ViewModels:
The first ViewModel (called PackageInfo) contains instances of objects created from an Entity Framework model.
The values in PackageInfo are being validated properly in the view by the baked-in "simple" MVC validation.

The second ViewModel (called PackageVals) contains DateTime values. 
The values in PackageVals are not being validated in the view.

Comment: What's the error you are receiving?

Comment: Also I notice your `DisplayFormat` attribute has a value of `{0:dd/MM/yyyy}` while your validation says that the format must be `mm/dd/yyyy`. Was this intentional?

Comment: The only time I'm seeing an error is if the form values get passed in, and they aren't date values. For instance, if I pass in "24ashugfdahu9ahgahui" in the DateIn field, I get a `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime` error. I'm trapping that in try-catch blocks in the Controller so the error never gets through, but then the user never knows why they didn't get any response.

Comment: I actually caught the mm/dd/yyyy error while writing this up and changed it in the code. I'll edit the post to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wound up being in the Controller, the only code I didn't post above. I think if I'd posted that initially then @Mystere Man or any of the other folks that were kind enough to try to help me out would have picked it up immediately.

What was going on was that I had made the argument of the Controller function a FormCollection variable rather than a model variable, so as a result the data was being passed in without ever being checked against the model's validations.

Here's the code that works:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RptPkgsRecd(PackageVals model)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentPage = "reports";
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                PackageVals pv = new PackageVals();
                pv.dps = regpacksRepository.GetSubmitted(model.datePass.DateIn, model.datePass.DateOut).ToList();
                return View(pv);
            }
            else
            {
                PackageVals pv = null;
                return View(pv);
            }
        }
        catch(SystemException ex)
        {
            var error = ex.ToString();
            this.ModelState.AddModelError(error, ex);
            PackageVals pv = null;
            return View(pv);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your DateTime values Nullable.  If you need them to be required, then make sure there is a required attribute on them.

If your objects cannot be nullable, then you need a View Model that is seperate from your data model.  A ViewModel allows you to customize it for the needs of the view irrespective of the needs of the data model.

Comment: I'll give the nullable a shot and let you know. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Making the DateTime values nullable didn't change anything. It's still allowing invalid strings to be passed back to the controller from the view without checking for valid date formats.

Comment: @War2d2 - Then i'm not sure what you're doing wrong, because I guarantee you that using a nullable datetime field will do validation on date format.  Try it with a simple view in a test app, and you will see what I mean.

Comment: It must be something wrong with how I'm implementing the ViewModel. I even tried moving the date values to their own partial class and applying the annotations there, and still had no luck. I'd post the ViewModel, view, and controller in their entirety, but there's a few hundred lines of code there.

Comment: It was how I was passing the ViewModel. I was passing the values to the Controller as form data rather than as the model. The DateTime vars didn't need to be made nullable. If I had posted the Controller code I think just about anyone would have been able to spot it. I was just looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @War2d2 - That would do it.  If you don't make the DateTime's nullable, then they will display with a default date/time format (probably 1/1/0001)